# Ionic 3 css loading controller

Tags: css, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

how to remove these white spaces
our 
fullscreen

[Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FAQaw.png)

```
  presentLoadingDefault() {
  let loading = this.loadingCtrl.create({
     spinner: 'hide',
      content: `<img src="assets/img/gif.gif"/>`
  });

  loading.present();

  setTimeout(() => {
    loading.dismiss();
  }, 5000);
}
```

Comment: you are just asking but you are not response any question

Answer (score 0):

The best way to know definitively is to use ionic serve and use google chrome "inspect" to search for the css that is applied to that element.

However, looking at your picture, I imagine that it is a margin that is being applied to the img tag.  So, you could try

you might also try 'padding: 0' as well.  (it's tough to know without looking at it with chrome developer tools)